# Angula2 input not binding

Tags: javascript, angular, binding

I am trying to  bind some data but is not working on

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 template : `<child [in]="25"></child>`
 })
export class AppComponent {}
```

and the child component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<h1>{{in}}</h1>',
})

export class ChildComponent {

   @Input()  in: string;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 template : `<child [in]="25"></child>`
 })
export class AppComponent {}

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '

## {{in}}

',
})

export class ChildComponent {

@Input()  in: string;
 }

Nothing wrong in this code .. every thing is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually assign a variable and then refer it. public Hello = "25";
Then  [in]="this.hello" 
 OR
Remove the brackets and assign directly
in ="25";

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of assigning values to an input of a component:
1) Either by passing directly the string value to the input from the template:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 template : `<child in="25"></child>`
 })
export class AppComponent {}
```

2) Or by binding the input to a variable defined in your class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 template : `<child [in]="myVar"></child>`
 })
export class AppComponent {
  public myVar: string = "25";
}
```

As a result you cannot bind the input to a numeric variable as you did here, simply because a variable defined in a class cannot be numeric (but it surely can be alphanumeric).